# Creating Functions off multiple SQL databases

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a function to work (Extremely new to functions btw) And this is what I have, but when I implement it into my page it doesn't turn any results. Is anybody able to see what's wrong in this?

```
public function get_character() {
        $con=mysql_connect("****","****","****");
        mysql_select_db("accounts", $con);
        $id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
        global $characterdb;
        $info = $characterdb->get_row("SELECT `name` FROM `characters` WHERE `account` = '" . $characterdb->escape($id) . "' AND `active`=1");
        if(is_object($info))
            return $info->character;
        else
            return '';
    }
```

Comment: add some basic debugging and you will see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$id` is a Mysql Result, not an integer that you can use in another query.
First you will need to get the row and the id from that row.

Also: consider handing $characterdb to the function as an argument or have it as a class variable.

Importing it via global is the least attractive option. ;)

Comment: It is possible that in $characterdb->escape($id), escape is a function where he is trying to get the id using mysql_fetch_array and returning it.

Comment: that would be an odd name for a function like that :)

Comment: I added a the result and set a variable based off of `code`$row['name']`code` and it solved my problem. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a field in your query. See below. Instead of name, it should be character in your select query.

```
$info = $characterdb->get_row("SELECT `character` FROM `characters` WHERE `account` = '" .   $characterdb->escape($id) . "' AND `active`=1");
    if(is_object($info))
        return $info->character;
    else
        return '';
```